# moodle scorm - finding api

Tags: javascript, xml, moodle, scorm

I'm using moodle 3.2 and trying to convert my html files into a scorm package. (A newbie)

As per my understanding moodle only supports scorm 1.2

I uploaded a scorm package (imsmanifest and a js file included which finds the api to start communication with LMS - LMSinitialize and LMSfinish) and it worked in moodle.

Then I uploaded a scorm package (included only imsfanifest file and not the js file) and this also worked in moodle.

Now, I'm unable to figure out if I need to use the api adapter finding js file with moodle or not.

I think this js ffile is required for features like bookmarking?

Please guide.
Thank you.

Comment: Anyone, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a algorithm to searching for "API" within windows in the browser.  This makes it so a IFRAME or a Tab/Popup Window can search the LMS.
Some LMS's use framesets still so its nested pretty much anywhere in all that.

I've said more on this wiki than I could ever type here so hopefully it will give you a head start.  https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki/The-Anti-Library.  Feel free to check out the actual full library if you feel you'll benefit from that.